# PHP Redirect with Cookies

Tags: php

How do I redirect to a splash page once with cookies?

I'm setting the cookie on my splash.php page to this:

```
<?php 
$expire = time()+60;
setcookie("no_splash", "1", $expire);
?>
```

On that page there's a link to my index.php with this:

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE['no_splash']== '1') {
    header("Location: index.php");
    echo "it works";
} else if($_COOKIE['no_splash']!= '1') {
    header("Location: splash.php");
};
?>
```

I keep getting a redirect loop error but can't figure why.

Comment: Your cookie expires after 60 seconds. Could that be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting to index.php from the index.php file, hence the loop.

Change your code to be simply

```
if($_COOKIE['no_splash'] != '1') {
    header("Location: splash.php");
    exit;
}
```

or indeed

```
if(!$_COOKIE['no_splash']) {
    header("Location: splash.php");
    exit;
}
```

which is the same thing.

Comment: +1 He just needs to remove his first conditional and leave the second.

Comment: Don't forget to remove that `;` after the bracket on the last line.

Comment: She (as in me, I might point out) just learned the hard way "exit;". Thank you!

Comment: Apologies if I've referenced you by gender - it wasn't deliberate.

Comment: ...and don't expect it to work in every browser - some ignore headers after a 30x status.

Answer (score 0):

```
$expire = time()+60;

header("Set-Cookie: no_splash=1; expires=$expire; path=/");
header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: You should always put `exit;` after the header redirect line too, otherwise PHP will still execute the rest of the file.

Comment: This doesn't accomplish anything different assuming his splash page is in his root dir.

Comment: The problem here isn't with the cookie, it's with the redirection to index.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply:

```
<?php
if($_COOKIE['no_splash']== '1') {
    echo "it works";
} else {
    header("Location: splash.php");
};
?>
```

Maybe `isset($_COOKIE['no_splash'])` rather than `$_COOKIE['no_splash']== '1'?
Also, not sure it this is what you want, but you can set simply not set the expiration time (or set it to 0), and it will delete the cookie when the browser is closed, so if they keep it open, they won't have to go back to the splash.

Comment: This will not work, as if the cookie exists when you visit the index page you'll be redirected to the index page, hence the loop.

Comment: Woops, yes, just need to remove the redirection, no?

Comment: There shouldn't be a redirect to index.php at all, I don't think.